# Simplify GeoJSON by retaining external boundaries (clustering)

Tags: leaflet, gis, geojson

I created a website (http://www.cartescolaire.paris) that basically loads a GeoJSON and displays it on a map using Leaflet.

This geoJSON is pretty large (over 2 Mb), the loading time can be very long (it doesn't even load on IE 11). More importantly the resulting map is not very responsive when zooming / navigating.

There are around 110 zones (clicking on a point in the map highlights the zone it belongs to), each of them made from dozens of polygons.

However the only important information that I want to visualize is the external boundaries of each zone.
Such a compressed geometry would be much more efficient performance-wise.

The complexity arises from the constraint that the zones shouldn't overlap. 
The final result should be disjoint clusters.

Any idea how I could do that ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,

You sound to need **merging** of polygons, so that you decrease your number of vector features, the weight of your GeoJSON file and map responsiveness. Keeping your resulting polygons disjoint should not be difficult.

You should have plenty resources on SO / GIS Stack Exchange  and Google on this, for example:

- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118223/merge-geojson-polygons-with-wgs84-coordinate
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118547/convert-geojson-with-multiple-polygons-and-multipolygons-into-single-multipolygo
- http://morganherlocker.com/post/Merge-a-Set-of-Polygons-with-turf/

(see also the related posts on SO on the right menu of this page, just above "Hot Network Questions")

Your case might be slightly different as most of your polygons are not adjacent, but are actually separated by empty areas / a margin (streets).

You might also be interested in [UTFGrid](https://github.com/mapbox/utfgrid-spec) for the interaction (clicking on the map to open the school associated with that area), as it would dramatically restore your map responsiveness: instead of vector shapes, you have the equivalent of tiles. See an example: http://danzel.github.io/Leaflet.utfgrid/example/map.html

However, I do not think you can visually show the areas with UTFGrid.

But you could combine this approach with canvas-based tiles, or even pre-generate tiles on your server and have them ready for display, rather than keeping a GeoJSON for client-side computation.

Bon courage !